# Usage of video.js useractive and userinactive events with videojs-overlay does not work immediately

Tags: events, video.js, dom-events, videojs-overlay

In a `video.js` player, I want to display information on the currently played video as an [videojs-overlay](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay) whenever the user is active (moving the mouse over the video) and hide the information when the user is inactive (not moving the mouse over the video).

I set `videojs-overlay` to listen to the `useractive` and `userinactive` events like this:

```
player.overlay({
  content: 'Default overlay content',
  debug: true,
  overlays: [{
    content: 'The user is active!',
    start: 'useractive',
    end: 'userinactive'
  }]
});
```

Unfortunately, the overlay is not triggered at first, but then, it starts working after the video is playing for ca. 1 minute.

Is there a problem with my setup, or might this be a bug in `videojs` or `videojs-overlay`? What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Those two events sound quite imprecise/not-well-defined to me.  'userinactive' is DEFINED as "...after a short delay..." here: https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#events Also, it won't work on a touch-screen device (e.g. tablet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video.JS already keeps track of the user active state using CSS classes. An example of this can be found in the [videojs-dock](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-dock) plugin. It uses the `vjs-user-inactive` and `vjs-user-active` CSS classes to control showing or hiding a dock or tray over the video that can be used to display information such as a title or description for the video. You may be able to use this as inspiration for your overlay.

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Disclaimer: I am employed by Brightcove.

Comment: I could easily adapt `videojs-dock` to fit my needs. Thank you very much for the hint, and for directing me to the `vjs-user-inactive` and `vjs-user-active` CSS classes. Of course, I am still curious, why the events `useractive` and `userinactive` did not work the way I expected.